# Cython: Import cython module variable from another pyx not declared in pxd header

Tags: python, cython

I wonder how to, if at all possible, import a variable from one cython module into another cython module when it is not declared in the header file.

Let's assume I have a (pre-compiled and non-alterable) library and its cython header file pxd.

**lib.pyx**

```
cdef double VAR1 = 1.0
cdef double VAR2 = 2.0
```

**lib.pxd**

```
cdef double VAR1
```

Now I would like to access VAR2 from another cython file. Is this possible? Accessing VAR1 works fine:

**app.pyx (1)**

```
from lib cimport VAR1
print VAR1
```

Results in

```
1.0
```

But trying to import VAR2 the same way fails:

**app.pyx (2)**

```
from lib cimport VAR1, VAR2
print VAR1, VAR2
```

Results in

```
CYTHON: app.pyx:1:0: 'VAR2.pxd' not found
CYTHON: app.pyx:1:23: Name 'VAR2' not declared in module 'lib'
```

I thought declaring VAR2 as extern might work, but it does not seem so:

**app.pyx (3)**

```
from lib cimport VAR1
cdef extern double VAR2
print VAR1, VAR2
```

Results in

```
PYTHON: ImportError: ./app.so: undefined symbol: VAR2
```

It seems to accept the definition, but does not see the symbol. Any idea if such an import is at all possible and if yes, how to achieve it? I've already tried all combinations of

```
import lib
cimport lib
from lib import *
from lib cimport *
```

Comment: Are you looking for the proper way to do this (which I think is "you can't") or a horrendous hack that will work in this one case because you aren't allowed to modify "lib.pxd" for some reason? If you're after a horrendous hack I suspect you start by inspecting the generated C code, and working out what Cython's actually called your variable (it will have decorated the name a bit) then trying `cdef extern ...`.

Comment: Why can't you modify the .pxd?

Comment: @DavidW: Thanks for the suggestion... but that seems like quite a hassle and reduce portability to next to nothing. Maybe I'll just have to accept the fact that it's impossible.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I am dealing with an existing library, scikit-learn, to be exact. My extension should be hooked onto the library, which is already compiled and installed.

Comment: @loli On a closer look I don't think it would have worked anyway - Cython defines the variables with static linkage, so they really shouldn't be visible outside the .c file they're defined in (which also may mean they're optimised away, or similar).